# Is it appropriate to use a ReactiveCollection in an API?

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

Is it appropriate to expose a ReactiveCollection in an API?  Specifically, in a service class that would be used internally on multiple applications. But as a thought experiment, we can also consider in public use as well.

I've been investigating Rx and ReactiveUI, and these seem like powerful tools.  However, I don't have enough experience with them to determine if it is a good idea to require others to take a dependency on them.

More details:

I'm creating a tracking service class that would track connected clients.  From my view, all that would be necessary for consumers to use this class is to expose an observable collection (possibly a ReactiveCollection) that exposes the connected clients, and notifies of changes to the collection which are managed by the service.  The entitity representing the connected clients would also take advantage of INotifyPropertyChanged to notify of updates to the clients' state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ReactiveCollection is a derivative of .NET's ObservableCollection (i.e. the non-Rx WPF/SL one), you could expose it as an ObservableCollection instead.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the work you've done on RxUI!
I would mainly be using the ReactiveCollection to expose the benefits to callers, inside this particular class I wouldn't be using much of the Rx features.

Comment: You could also expose the ItemsAdded / ItemsObserved Observables as separate properties (i.e. just have it return the one in ReactiveCollection) - since IO<T> is built into the framework, you can include it as a property easily

Comment: That's a pretty good idea, I think I will give that a shot. That should also allow me to expose the ObservableCollection as a ReadOnlyObservableCollection.